# Angular 7 Headers aren't getting set

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using Angular 7 and created a interceptor to include auth token in every request.

Here is my interceptor code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: token
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

The node api to verify auth token:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.headers['authorization']; // Coming Undefined 
    if (!token)
        return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });
    jwt.verify(token, 'top_secret', function (err, decoded) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        // if everything good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.userId = decoded.user.email;
        next();
    });
}

module.exports = verifyToken;
```

When hitting the API with Postman things are working fine but when sent a request using angular code the headers aren't received at node API.

[image: Request header when sent from angular]

[image: Request header when sent from Postman]

[image: Network Tab Details]

[image: Request object sent from browser]
What could be the possible reason for this kind of strange behavior?

Comment: @lealceldeiro, Yes i tried this and found that its not the actual error.
Edited my code.

Comment: Javascript differentiates between upper- and lower case characters. As lealcedeiro mentioned, you're setting the ```Authorization``` header, while expecting ```authorization```. However, you're not receiving ```Authorization``` either, so that's not the problem. Have you checked your network tab while making the request to confirm that the header is being injected into the request?

Comment: @TimVN, yes I'm not getting any of the values either authorization or this Authorization. I have updated the question with network tab details.

Comment: Have you tried ```request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': token
            },
            withCredentials: true
        });```

Comment: Is your `JwtInterceptor` correctly called?

Comment: @TimVN, Yes i did and this way of sending headers is also not working.

Comment: @youri, yes i added debugger and its getting hit also logged the final request in the console. Edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you are showing is for a OPTIONS request, required for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You need to enable CORS in nodejs

First, install the `cors` module

```
npm install cors
```

Then use it in your nodejs backend

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Thanks David, It worked. But I'm still confused that why earlier it worked fine with Postman?

Comment: @ArjunSingh Postman, do some stuff behind scenes on your behalf when makings such requests. One of the reasons it does it, is to avoid, for example CORS errors.

Comment: @ArjunSingh: CORS is only implemented by browsers, not by clients like POSTMAN. That's why there is no OPTIONS request when using POSTMAN

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an interceptor and cloning the request in combination with authorisation.

I had to add content type and accept headers and tell the server it is json:

```
  setHeaders: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept'       : 'application/json',
    'Authorization': '' // your token
  }
```

Comment: I tried in this way but the results are same. The headers didn't changed from what i shared in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like that

```
request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set(
        'Authorization',
        localStorage.getItem('token')
      )
    })
```